# Android: linear layout issue

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am facing hardtime with linear layout, in my linear layout i have two images these images are in opposite ends, but when iam changing the screen orientation the cancel button is comming in the middle

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"          
            android:src="@drawable/askabud" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fbcancel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"         
            android:paddingLeft="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/fbcancel" />
         <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/quesspinner"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:entries="@array/fblist"
            android:visibility="gone" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

not sure where iam going wrong. Any help is appreciated.

here is my complete xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"          
            android:src="@drawable/askabud" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fbcancel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"         
            android:paddingLeft="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/fbcancel" />
         <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/quesspinner"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:entries="@array/fblist"
            android:visibility="gone" />

 </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0.7dip"
            android:background="#3b5998" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="165dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/autodelete"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fbshare"
                android:src="@drawable/autodelete" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/autodelete"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/autodelete" 
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:entries="@array/fblist" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/fbedittext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="135dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fbshare"
                android:background="@drawable/roundcorners"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/fbhint"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/fbshare"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fbedittext"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/newfb1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/fbpeople"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/autodelete"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fbshare"
                android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                android:src="@drawable/people2" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/placeName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" 
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"  />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/placeAddress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" 
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/fbtext"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**:

Try this

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="left"    >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
         android:gravity="right"
         >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fbcancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"         
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
         <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/quesspinner"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

### According to your requirement it will work...

Try to design separately for the land scape mode. You can do that by creating the file of same name in the directory res/layout-land. If you don't have a separate design for the Land scape than fix your Screen orientation to Potrait mode. You can do that in Activity level as well as in Application level. To set the fixed orientation use  `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`

Comment: when i used relativelayout for the same design i dont have a pblm..no when i change to linearlayout everything works except the cancel image

Comment: he is talking about making multiple layouts within different folders with different resource identifiers such as orientations, screen size, density etc. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers

Comment: @teekib check the answer...I have checked it in land scape and potrait mode

Comment: tried withyour code ..both the images are coming in the middle..i want them in the right and left corners

Comment: @Pragnani just now did..thax a lot ..perfect

Answer (score 0):

> but when iam changing the screen orientation the cancel button is
>   comming in the middle

This is a little bit vague explanation of what is happening.

I'm guessing switching from landscape to portrait?

You aren't explaining how you want it to look and how it looks now. (In portrait and landscape). There don't seem to be an error, so if you want us to help you without us having to recreate all your code and strings and values.

Have you tried changing the paddingLeft of your cancelButton. It seems in portrait mode, it can be possible there isn't enough space to put those two imageviews next to each other, effectively pushing the other bottom and 200dp away from the left side.

Comment: in portrait mode it s in correct position but in landscape other views are extending but the this cancel image is still in same position